# Inserting name into database, getting korean signs as output

Tags: oracle-xe, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

Trying to insert simple xml file with one row in IIB with simple message flow into Oracle XE DB. Message flow works fine and inserts data into database, but data written in db is different from starting data. For example, as I'm trying to insert my name "Dino" I'd get Korean/Japanese/Chinese signs in return.

I've tried changing XML formats thinking there might be problem, but I suppose it has to do with encoding.

- Input:

[image]

- Output in DB:

[image]

This is how my compute node looks like:

```
    CREATE COMPUTE MODULE SimpleDB_mf_Compute 

CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
     CALL CopyMessageHeaders();
    -- CALL CopyEntireMessage();
    INSERT INTO Database.dkralj.emp VALUES(InputRoot.XMLNSC.emp.name);
    SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.DBINSERT.STATUS='SUCCESS';
    RETURN TRUE;
END;

CREATE PROCEDURE CopyMessageHeaders() BEGIN
    DECLARE I INTEGER 1;
    DECLARE J INTEGER;
    SET J = CARDINALITY(InputRoot.*[]);
    WHILE I < J DO
        SET OutputRoot.*[I] = InputRoot.*[I];
        SET I = I + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;

CREATE PROCEDURE CopyEntireMessage() BEGIN
    SET OutputRoot = InputRoot;
END;
    END MODULE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the IBM documentation for the [INSERT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak05050_.htm) statement in ESQL  it might be worth trying.

```
INSERT INTO Database.dkralj(NAME) VALUES(InputRoot.XMLNSC.emp.name);
```

If weird things are still happening then I'd try a string constant to avoid any issues with character coding in the input message.

```
INSERT INTO Database.dkralj(NAME) VALUES('TheEmpValue');
```

Before this statement in your code

```
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.DBINSERT.STATUS='SUCCESS';
```

You should check for success or otherwise by using the inbuilt SQLSTATE, SQLCODE, SQLERRORTEXT to check the result of your call.

```
IF NOT ((SQLCODE = 0) OR (SQLSTATE = '01000' AND SQLNATIVEERROR = 8153)) THEN
    -- Do something about the error.
    -- The check of SQLSTATE and SQLNATIVEERROR covers warnings
    -- The 8153 is for Microsoft SQL Server other databases may use a different value
END IF;
```

Also check the codepages aka CodedCharSetId of the source system data, the message in IIB and the default codepage of the database.

Use mqsicvp MYBROKER -n ODBC_DB_NAME to get other details about the connection you need to use -n to get the details.

Use something like DBeaver to add some data. Have a look at the datatype specified for the field.

As per your comment below and my response here is an example of a PASSTHRU statement. Note the use of the ? to avoid SQL Injection.

```
PASSTHRU('SELECT RTRIM(A.EMPLID) AS EMPLID,
       RTRIM(A.ADDRESS_TYPE) AS ADDRESS_TYPE,
       RTRIM(A.ADDR_TYPE_DESCR) AS ADDR_TYPE_DESCR,
       CAST(RTRIM(A.EFFDT) AS DATE) AS EFFDT,
       RTRIM(A.EFF_STATUS) AS EFF_STATUS,
       RTRIM(A.ADDRESS1) AS ADDRESS1,
       RTRIM(A.ADDRESS2) AS ADDRESS2,
       RTRIM(A.ADDRESS3) AS ADDRESS3,
       RTRIM(A.ADDRESS4) AS ADDRESS4,
       RTRIM(A.CITY) AS CITY,
       RTRIM(A.STATE) AS STATE,
       RTRIM(A.POSTAL) AS POSTAL
FROM ADDRESS_VW AS A 
WHERE UPPER(A.EMPLID) = ?') VALUES(AggrRef.EmployeeID)
```

Comment: Hello @TJA , tried your suggestion but didn't work. I've found a solution together with my co-worker. It seems that when you pass insert function inside passthru function everything works. Its pretty weird syntax but it works. Here is how it looks:     PASSTHRU 'INSERT INTO dkralj.emp (name) VALUES ('''||InputRoot.XMLNSC.emp.name||''')' to Database.LocalDB;

Comment: Hello @Dino I use PASSTHRU a lot. Just be careful about the potential for SQL Injection. I've added an example to my answer.